# React: Understanding the passing of Dynamic Content

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am following a course by **[Maximilian Schwarzmüller](https://www.udemy.com/react-the-complete-guide-incl-redux/)** on Udemy and I am stuck in one of his explanations.

Earlier he did something like (below)

```
  <input type="text" onChange={props.changed} value={props.name} />
```

and in App JS

```
changed={this.eventSwitchHandler}
```

To change the input of the name as we type. this is my eventSwitchHandler

```
eventSwitchHandler = (event) => {
  this.setState({
    person: [
    {name: "shivom", age: 23},
    {name: event.target.value, age: 23},
    {name: "Vaibhav", age: 58}
    ]
  })
}
```

This was when our content was static and only worked on the second element, Now when we kinda have our content as dynamic for example

```
  render() {
    let person = null;

    if (this.state.showPerson) {
      person= (
        <div>
          {
            this.state.person.map((el, index) => {
              return <Person
              key={el.id}
              click={this.deletePersonHandler.bind(index)}
              name={el.name}
              age={el.age}

            })
          }
       </div>
     );
    }
```

He is doing something like this for change event

```
changed={(event) => this.eventSwitchHandler(event, person.id)}
```

He mentioned (During the first example, when our content was static that react automatically passes the event to eventSwitchHandler but now he is taking event as argument in anonymous function.

Can someone explain the reason for the same since his explanation here was  sort of vague?

Here is what we were doing in comparison previously

```
return (

//--//-- lecture 1
  //---// -- we wrote this in lecture (JSX code) -> (1le)
  <div className="App">
        <h1> Hi I am react App</h1>
        <button onClick={this.switchEventHandler.bind(this, "Hait")}>Button</button>
        <Person
          name={this.state.person[0].name}
          age={this.state.person[0].age}>
        </Person>
        <Person
          name={this.state.person[1].name}
          age={this.state.person[1].age}
          click={this.switchEventHandler.bind(this, "rahul")}
          changed={this.eventSwitchHandler} >
        </Person>
        <Person
          name={this.state.person[2].name}
          age={this.state.person[2].age} > (son of Hariom)
        </Person>
       </div>
     )
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the static case the `eventSwitchHandler` always changed the `name` property for the same person. In the second example it has to know which persons name has to change as every name change has to be handled by this handler.

So instead of directly passing that handler to the `<Person>` component we pass an arrow function that additionally calls the handler with the person id when called. In other words the function itself stores which person it should call the `eventSwitchHandler` for.

This is a common approach when [passing additional arguments to event handlers](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html#passing-arguments-to-event-handlers) but it has one caveat:

The problem with this syntax is that a different callback is created each time the component renders. In most cases, this is fine. However, if this callback is passed as a prop to lower components, those components might do an extra re-rendering.